# Content security policy headers and header size

Tags: http, header, content-security-policy

Have any recommendations for a large content-security-policy http header?  Some applications cannot handle reading from a large content-security header, due to limitations on header packet size.  Yet to list the domains required for a site, specifically, that takes bytes for each domain.  Have you observed this limitation of the spec and how did you work around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In practice, there were 2 types of restrictions on the size of the HTTP header - server side and client side:

- The maximum size of all HTTP response headers for the Apache web server, by default it is 8190 bytes.
  If the total size of all HTTP headers (CSP + "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + Content-type:"text/html; charset=utf-8" + all others) exceeds the allowed limit, the web server returns error 502.
- limiting the size of the receiving buffer on some mobile devices. It can be detected by violation reports, the `original-policy` field is truncated in them. Last observed about 6 years ago.

To fix the problem:

- use `*` to whitelist a set of subdomains (*.google.com).
- use `img-src *` to allow images from any, since XSS through images is unlikely.
- use the `'strict-dynamic'` token in the `script-src` directive and remove all host-based sources from it, except `http: https:`. See [strict CSP](https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html) by Google for details.